# unix real time vs python process_time()

Tags: python, time

I'm running an external script using `subprocess.run(...)` with an external executable that I know very little about.

I've surrounded the `run()` call with a couple of time calls:

```
import subprocess
import time

t1_start = time.perf_counter()
t2_start = time.process_time()
cmdout = subprocess.run(['executable', '-arg', 'val'], capture_output=True)
t1_end = time.perf_counter()
t2_end = time.process_time()
print('real time: %f' %(t1_end-t1_start))
print('user time: %f' %(t2_end-t2_start))
```

`executable` is a third-party commercially-sensitive code binary that I can't share.

When I run this, I get something like

```
$ python my_script.py
real time: 7.9063631325456365
user time: 1.0106746650250822
```

but when I call the python script with `time`:

```
$ time python my_script.py
real time: 7.9063631325456365
user time: 1.0106746650250822

real    0m3.078s
user    0m1.464s
sys     0m0.359s
```

I'm not clear why there is so much discrepancy between the result of `perf_counter()` and the `real` time that unix returns.

As I understood it, `time.process()` is the process time (is this total CPU time, i.e. `user` + `sys`?), and `time.perf_counter()` should(?) be approximately equivalent to `real` - but my results would make it seem this isn't the case?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Most likely there's more there is to your `my_script.py` file. For starters the code you've posted doesn't even work. Please post the full code.

Comment: @freakish `executable` is third party commercial code that I can't share - my question was more about trying to understand what `time.process()` and `time.perf_counter()` are measuring, and why this is so different to any values `real`, `user`, and `sys` return

Comment: I don't care about `executable`, it is unlikely it affects the issue. The code doesn't work because there are imports missing, there is an invalid print, etc. Post [a miminal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @freakish I know all about that link - in this instance, because I can't provide the executable, you will never be able to run the code in the way that I can. I was hoping to get some help understanding the intricacies of the different time methods. This is obviously not possible. To appease you, I shall have to delete the question

Comment: You keep talking about the executable like it matters. Does it? If you know that it does then there's no point in talking about Python at all. If it doesn't then clearly you have an issue with your script that is not visibile to us. That's because you haven't posted your full code. The only way to be sure is to post full Python code. Otherwise, are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Yes, apart from the missing import statement you politely reminded me about, that is my full code

Comment: If that's the full code then the issue is related to either `executable` or some external factor (e.g. machine's load).

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you mean by 'some external factor'

Comment: Have you tried calling your timing script (the one you have shown) with `time`? Then you will have the timing measurements from both mechanisms from the exact same execution run

Comment: @lxop do you mean `time executable -arg val`?

Comment: No I mean `time python <your-timing-script.py>`

Comment: Wait, are you saying that `my_script.py` is not the timing script?

Comment: @lxop sorry, I'm not sure how that is different to what I've got at the end of the question?

Comment: @ChrisW Now that I think about it I can't find a resonable explanation for the discrepancy between `time` and `perf_counter`. Unless `my_script.py` is not the timing script.

Comment: I'm assuming it isn't, since it doesn't appear to have printed `real time:` and `user time:`

Comment: OK thanks for updating

Comment: How long does the script _actually_ take to run? i.e., with a stopwatch?

Comment: About 3 seconds

Comment: Is it likely that `executable` would do anything strange with system clocks? I don't know much about the clock used by `perf_counter` but I'm wondering if `executable` is somehow altering the counter value

Comment: Here's an experiment: run another python script that just prints the value of `perf_counter()` and sleeps for 1 second and loops forever (you could also print the difference since the last value for convenience). With that running, run your timing test. See if there are any anomalies in the output of your new script during the timing test.

Comment: Did you try this? Any results?

Comment: @lxop no executable can alter clock unless it is started with root privileges (at least under Unix). That would be very bad.

Comment: @freakish The experiment would still provide an interesting insight. OP: It would also help to print the actual value of the perf_counter before and after the run (not just the difference) to see that it matches the value seen by the second python process

Comment: @freakish since we don't have any idea what the `executable` is, it might be running with root privileges, either directly from the script or with suid

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't work as-is.

```
    print('real time: ' + t1_end-t1_start)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Fixing that, I can't seem to reproduce the problem on my Mac (and not knowing your `executable`, I just decided to throw random numbers into the bit bucket instead):

```
import time, subprocess

t1_start = time.perf_counter()
t2_start = time.process_time()
subprocess.run('dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=100m count=1', shell=True)
t1_end = time.perf_counter()
t2_end = time.process_time()
print('real time: ', (t1_end-t1_start))
print('user time: ', (t2_end-t2_start))
```

---

```
bash-4.4$ time python3 so53724371.py
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes transferred in 3.286906 secs (31901612 bytes/sec)
real time:  3.3021506880000002
user time:  0.001468999999999998

real    0m3.354s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m3.303s
bash-4.4$
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting that in this case the `sys` and `time.process()` times are so similar - my question was trying to understand why unix `sys`, `real`, and `user` times, and the values that the python functions return are so different

Comment: For this example the `sys` time will be a large fraction of the total time because the executable being used is basically just doing system operations